# How to find out the different data types for sparse matrices in R

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

When using the `fac2sparse` command in [r](/questions/tagged/r) I can decide in the `to` option whether the entries should be of type `c("d", "i", "l", "n", "z")` . The help only says that the standard option is `d` which stands for double. I can guess that the next two are integer and logic, I read somewhere that `n` stands for pattern and I have no idea what `z` stands for.

This shouldn't require guessing, so where in the help files can find this information? I looked around in the related help pages and the general matrix documentation but I didn't find it.

Comment: honestly no idea what 'n' stands for. as near as I can tell it's not supported. from the source code, z stands for complex: https://github.com/cran/Matrix/blob/13baa504e0e1ede81c41388d01ae28662acf62d8/R/spModels.R#L20

Comment: pretty sure "n" create an nsparseMatrix class - see `?ngCMatrix-class`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see it in the [source code](https://github.com/cran/Matrix/blob/master/R/spModels.R),

```
if (to != "n") 
    df$x <- rep.int(switch(to, d = 1, i = 1L, l = TRUE, z = 1 + 
        (0+0i)), nrow(df))
```

so like you said, d is double, i is integer, l is logical, z is complex number with 1 on the real with 0 on the imaginary part. I am not sure how you transform something from factor to complex number though.

And as @dww correctly pointed out, "n" creates a nsparsematrix, where only the positional information is stored:

```
fac2sparse(factor(c(1:3,1:2)),to="l")@x
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE

fac2sparse(factor(c(1:3,1:2)),to="d")@x
[1] 1 1 1 1 1

fac2sparse(factor(c(1:3,1:2)),to="n")@x
Error: no slot of name "x" for this object of class "ngCMatrix"
```